# jQuery селектор для скрытых first-child

Tags: jquery, javascript

Приветствую.

Не могу составить правильный селектор для выбора скрытых элементов.

Вот пример: http://jsfiddle.net/8Uyn8/

Хочется дробится чтобы при каждом срабатывании показывалось по одному элементу в каждой секции.

Буду рад любым идеям, и ссылкам =)

Заранее ОГРОМНОЕ спасибо!

Answer (score 2):

Тут долго можно извращаться, но так как вы сделали элементам отдельный стиль, который их скрывает, то почему бы не удалять этот стиль по очереди? Смотрим [результат тут](http://jsfiddle.net/Deonis/8Uyn8/1/)

```
var i = 0,
    but = $('#showNext'),
    sect = $('section');
but.click(function(){
    sect.each(function(){
        $(this).children('.item').eq(i).removeClass('hidden-item');
    });
    i++;
});
```

Comment: Зачем делать отдельные переменные для `#showNext` и `section`, если они вызываются только в одном месте каждый?

Comment: @Crasher, Дело привычки... к тому же, не самой плохой.

Comment: @Deonis, но ведь тут это совсем неуместно и это может негативно повлиять на понимание алгоритма автором вопроса

Comment: @Crasher, как-то нет настроения холиварить.

Comment: @Crasher , section вызывается при каждом клике ага.

Answer (score -1):

Ответ похожий на ответ Deonis, но используя селектор по `children` и `:not(:visible):`

JS:

```
$('#showNext').click(showOneElementInEachSection);
var sect=$('section');

function showOneElementInEachSection() {
    sect.each(function () {
        $(this).children('.hidden-item:not(:visible)').first().fadeIn(100);
    });
}
```

[демо](http://jsfiddle.net/oceog/zS4KZ/)

---

второй вариант - убирать класс:

```
$('#showNext').click(showOneElementInEachSection);
var sect=$('section');

function showOneElementInEachSection() {
    sect.each(function () {
        $(this).children('.hidden-item').first().removeClass('hidden-item');
    });
}
```

[демо](http://jsfiddle.net/oceog/zS4KZ/1/)